# Codeigniter 3 + HMVC Module (cgi/fastcgi vs apache handler)

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc, server-configuration

I have an installation of CI 3 + HMVC Extension (https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) working fine on my local webserver. 
However on the public server, this script:

```
<?php echo modules::run("menu"); ?>
```

won't be executed.

The main difference between the servers, will be probably:

Local:
Server API: Apache 2 Handler

Public:
Server API: CGI / FastCGI

Also I get an Error 404 when I try to call the different pages, e.g. domain.com/artist, domain.com/events, etc. The pages works fine on the local server.

Comment: `domain.com` landing page working?

Comment: Yes. The mainpage ist working

Comment: probably there `.htaccess` issue try once url `domain.com/index.php/events` if it's work then `.htaccess` `RewriteBase` issue

Comment: domain.com/index.php/events unfortunatelly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing modules wrong.

**View**

With this: You must include the **module-name/controller-name/function**

```
<?php echo Modules::run("module-name/controller-name/index"); ?>
```

- application
- modules
- modules > module-name
- modules > module-name > controllers
- modules > module-name > controllers > Controller-name.php

As shown https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: I've changed it to '<?php echo Modules::run("menu/menu/index"); ?>' but it still doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was Capital letters in the filenames of Models and Controllers. Changed all Models/Controllers to Capital letter and everything works fine.